# Java Observer does not update when GUI window is not on top

Tags: java, observer-pattern, observable

I searched but I didn't find any solution to a similar problem. I have a problem with an Observer/Observable pattern. The Observable is implemented at a class called "firstmap" and the classes are:

```
class ObservableValue extends Observable{
    private String n;
    public ObservableValue(String n)
       {
          this.n = n;
       }
    public void setValue(String n)
       {
          this.n = n;
          setChanged();
          notifyObservers();

       }
       public String getValue()
       {
          return n;
       }
}

public class TextObserver implements Observer
{
private ObservableValue ov = null;
private multiwindow window1;
public TextObserver(ObservableValue ov, multiwindow window1)
{
  this.ov = ov;
  this.window1=window1;
}
public void update(Observable obs, Object obj)
{
  if (obs == ov)
  {
     System.out.println(ov.getValue());
     String[] tmp = ov.getValue().split(",");
     window1.destMessage(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
  }
}
}
```

The problem is that the update is only executed when the window "firstmap" is on the foreground. Otherwise, it is not updated until I bring the window to the foreground. Is there any way to make it update even when it's running on the background?
Thanks.

edit: I didn't mention that "firstmap" is a JFrame.

edit2: Some more details:

The "firstmap" is a map showing the movement of objects. When an object reaches a specific position, I want a message to appear to another JFrame ("multiwindow"). The way the code is now, the message appears only when the "firstmap" is on the foreground.

In the "firstmap" class there is

```
ObservableValue ov = new ObservableValue("");
TextObserver to = new TextObserver(ov, window1);
public firstmap() {
    this.setTitle("Map");
    ov.addObserver(to);
    window1.setVisible(true);
    canvas = new DrawCanvas();
    this.setContentPane(canvas);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.pack();
    this.setSize(width, height);
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
    timer.start();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

...

```
for (int i = 0; i < window1.getaircraftlist().size(); i++) {

            if (window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getReached()==false) {
                g.drawImage(window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getImage(), window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getX(), 
                    window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getY(), this);

            }
            else {
                if (((window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getDestFixPointName()=="IAF")||(window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getDestFixPointName()=="AIRPORT")) && k[i]==0){
                    g.drawImage(window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getImage(), window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getX(), 
                            window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getY(), this);
                    ov.setValue(window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).name+","+window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getDestFixPointName());
                    k[i]=1;

                }
                else if (((window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getDestFixPointName()=="IAF")||(window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getDestFixPointName()=="AIRPORT")) & k[i]==1){
                    g.drawImage(window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getImage(), window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getX(), 
                            window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getY(), this);
                }
                else
                {
                    ov.setValue(window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).name+","+window1.getaircraftlist().get(i).getDestFixPointName());
                    window1.getaircraftlist().remove(i);}
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to get away with calling repaint() on the JFrame object in the background - this should add the offending dimensions to the painting algorithm running on the EDT.

If this fails to update the GUI then it is a sign that the changes to the observed model have not been propagated to the JFrame model.

Comment: I already have the repaint() method in the "firstmap" class. The "firstmap" implements ActionListener and I have the method:   `@Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  updateCraft();
  repaint();
 }`

Comment: are you sure the actionPerformed event is being fired?

Comment: Yes, it is being fired when the window is on the foreground because I can see the changes on it.

Comment: Is the paint() method of the background JFrame being called by the EDT?  Override paint() with super.paint(); System.out.println(this) to see.  If you see the println then the issue is with the model, if you don't then you need to trigger a revalidation.

Comment: I only see it when the window is on the foreground. When i take it to the background it stops. So?

Comment: Therefore, you need to signal to the EDT that you want to recalc that window too when you do your action - call revalidate() to the background window.

Comment: Unfortunately not working, seems like it has no effect at all.